# pytest-django test case doesn't see objects created with migrations

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I have an odd problem with a test case like:

```
pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


def test_foo_bar():
    root_page = Site.objects.first().root_page
```

The issue is that the Site object, that by default should be created by Wagtail's migration, is not always (but sometimes, oddly, it is) accessible in the above test.
The strange thing is, that when the test is ran with a specified path (`pytest <path_to_file>.py::test_foo_bar`) then the site is fetched correctly.

I use these plugins:
`mock-3.11.1, randomly-3.12.0, django-4.5.2, Faker-18.11.2, sugar-0.9.7, snapshottest-0.6.0`